# ssh-askpass on Mac OS 10.9/Mavericks broken?

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, ssh-agent

On Mac OS 10.7 and 10.8 (separate computers) I've been using a ssh-askpass script to let me verify the use of SSH keys:

https://github.com/TimZehta/mac-ssh-confirm

However, this does not seem to work on Mavericks/10.9?

Plain SSH keys works fine:

```
box ~$ ssh-add -D
All identities removed.
box ~$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa: 
Identity added: /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa (/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa)
box ~$ ssh remotehost
remotehost ~$
^D
```

But with -c, it no longer works..

```
box ~$ ssh-add -D
All identities removed.
box ~$ ssh-add -c ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa: 
Identity added: /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa (/Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa)
The user must confirm each use of the key
box ~$ ssh remotehost
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
Password for user@remotehost:
```

/usr/libexec/ssh-askpass is owned by root and has +x. It does not even get executed it seems (added simple "touch a-logfile" line, never called).

Any ideas or hints on how to debug further?

Thanks

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: Doh.. Must have navigated away from the apple.stackexchange.com during the loginflow somehow.

Reposted here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131385/ssh-askpass-on-mac-os-10-9-mavericks-broken

Answer (score 1):

FYI: Resolved, ssh-agent requires DISPLAY env var to be set.

Details at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131385/ssh-askpass-on-mac-os-10-9-mavericks-broken/131532#131532